# Everything freezes when enabling monitor mode

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, freeze

`Ubuntu` freezes and everything stops working when I try to set my wifi into `monitor mode`.

```
ifconfig wlo1 down
iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
ifconfig wlo1 up
```

This is the way I am turning the monitor mode on.My interface name is `wlo1` and my Network Interface card is `rtl8723de` which supports monitor mode ,I have checked it by running `iw list`:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * mesh point
```

I am using :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:20.04
Codename:focal
```

kernel: `5.8.0-36-generic`

After the command `ifconfig wlo1 up` Ubuntu totally freezes and I have to restart it in order to start working again.I have dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 10.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe due to network manager fighting for the  device ,  you need to set interface to  non managed mode

Edited : First part un-necessary

- Type in `sudo /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and find the option `managed=true` , change it to `managed=false`
- restart network manager using `systemctl restart NetworkManager` or reboot pc

Note: You will need to  manually configure your network ip address , try using nmcli for that (from memory)

Comment: Hey nothing exist in that file.It opens a new file when I run command `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`.What should I do?

Comment: Check updated possible solution

Comment: its already like this : `[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no`